# Diagonal Matrices in J

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, j

I do a lot of work with eigenvalues and hence building / unbuilding diagonal matrices is something I do a lot.  In the spirit of J, I've come up with some simple definitions, but wonder if I have missed a simpler way?  I couldn't find anything in the phrasebook, but may have been looking in the wrong place.

Make Diagonal matrix from list of diagonal entries:

```
diag =: * =@i.@#
```

Extract diagonal entries from a matrix:

```
extract =: +/@(* =@i.@#)
```

Comment: There are relevant definitions in `math/mt` and `math/lapack`

Comment: Now I know where to look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diagonal entries of a matrix have a standar definition in J:

```
extract =: (<0 1)&|:
```

This is, unfortunately, hidden somewhere in the vocabulary. (You can see it passing in [transpose](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d232.htm))

I usually use diag as

```
diag =: 3 :'(2##y) $ ,_1 (((#y)#0),~])\y'
```

but I no longer remember why. Your version is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
   (* =) 2 3 4
2 0 0
0 3 0
0 0 4
```

If you are working with unique elements.

```
diag=: * = NB. a hook defined tacitly

   diag 89 3 56.6
89 0    0
 0 3    0
 0 0 56.6
```

The `=` breaks down if the elements are not unique as the matrix is no longer square

```
   diag 3 4 4
|length error: diag
|       diag 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution involves using "copy-fill".

```
diag =: (2 ##) $ (#~ 1 j. #)
```

This is longer than OP's original formulation, but it works for both numbers and characters (as long as you want spaces to play the role of zero).

Short explanation (primarily for "future me", as I'm fairly new to J):

Consider the following example (with `y =: 1 2 5 7` representing the diagonal entries):

```
4 4 $ 1j4 # y NB. the required diagonal matrix
```

The complex number argument `1j4` to the left of `#` inserts 4 zeros after every copied item from `y`. Reshaping this into a 4 x 4 matrix gives the diagonal matrix.

The `4`'s above are nothing but the number of items in y: `#y`. So we can generalise as `(2 # #y) $ (1 j. #y) # y`. The tacit equivalent of this is given at the top.